# Using literal in include (literal join) with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem implementing a join to stored procedure that return a table, The problem is: I have a stored procedure who returns me one uuid (and others fields), To apply as a filter to the real query I thought to use an Inner join, example:

```
SELECT
    ot.*
FROM
    "OriginalTable" as ot
INNER JOIN "MyStoredProcedures"(param1, params2) as enableds
    ON ot.uuid = enableds.uuid
...
```

Something like:

```
OriginalModel.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: sequelize.fn('MyStoredProcedures', param1, param2),
        required: true,
    }],
});
```

But I realized it isn't supported, getting:

> TypeError: include.model.getTableName is not a function

There are some way to do an inner join with a literal  like value?

Thanks, sorry my poor english

Comment: is param1 and param2 attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

you can call the stored procedure and *then* make your join:

```js
const newTable = await sequelize.query(
    'CALL MyStoredProcedures (:param1, :param2)', 
    {replacements: { param1: "value1", param2: "value2", }}
)

OriginalModel.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: newTable,
          required: true,
    }],
});
```